# How to send 2dimensional array to another activity

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity, bundle

I am sending one 2D array from one activity to another using bundle, but on the reception end I get the error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[][]

the code for your consideration is provided

```
    obj_res = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_result);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[][] table = (String[][])bundle.getSerializable("table");

    for(int a=0;a<30;a++) { //to display array data
                for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++) {

                    obj_res.append(String.valueOf(table[a][b]));
                }
                obj_res.append("\n");
            }
```

please help me in this mater of if there is any other convenient way to pass 2D array

Comment: how did you insert the object in the bundle?

Comment: @pooya 
Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putSerializable("table", table);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, array_receive.class);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

While sending:

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("arr", your2dArray);
Intent i = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

While receiving:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) b.getSerializable("arr");
String[][] arr = new String[objectArray.length][];
for(int i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++) {
    arr[i]=(String[]) objectArray[i];
}
```

Comment: it says that required is array[] while found is array[][] mean it is not accepting 2d array

Comment: i have not used it but i guess it will convert the 2d into one array or am i getting it wtrong. beside the array will have the row equivalent to the total fields in 2d array. i am not sure just asking.

Answer (score 0):

The simple simple way to send data serial objects across activities is you should use GSON library by google

First covert the object to json text then send text to second activity and in the second activity convert that json back to object

Hope this might help.